# Use jQuery to replace XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am quite new to JavaScript libraries. I wanted to replace my current code with jQuery. My current code looks like this:

```
var req;

function createRequest() {
   var key = document.getElementById("key");
   var keypressed = document.getElementById("keypressed");
   keypressed.value = key.value;
   var url = "/My_Servlet/response?key=" + escape(key.value);
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      req = new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
      req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   req.open("Get", url, true);
   req.onreadystatechange = callback;
   req.send(null);
}

function callback() {
   if (req.readyState == 4) {
      if (req.status == 200) {
         var decimal = document.getElementById('decimal');
         decimal.value = req.responseText;
      }
   }
   clear();
}
```

I wanted to replace my code with something a little friendlier like jQuery's

```
$.get(url, callback);
```

However it doesn't call my callback function.

Also I would like to call a function called `createRequest` continuously. Does jQuery have a nice way of doing that?
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 19):

```
$.get(url, {}, callback);
```

should do the trick. Your callback could be simplified like this:

```
function callback(content){
    $('#decimal').val(content);
}
```

Or even shorter:

```
$.get(url, {}, function(content){
    $('#decimal').val(content);
});
```

And all in all I think this should work:

```
function createRequest() {
    var keyValue = $('#key').val();
    $('#keypressed').val(keyValue);
    var url = "/My_Servlet/response";
    $.get(url, {key: keyValue}, function(content){
        $('#decimal').val(content);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Take out the readyState and status checks.  jQuery only calls your callback upon success.  Your callback is supplied the arguments `(data, textStatus)`, so you should use `data` instead of `req.responseText`.

`window.setTimeout()` as suggested by another answer won't do what you want - that only waits and then calls your function once.  You need to use `window.setInterval()` instead, which will call your function periodically until you cancel it.

So, in summary:

```
var interval = 500; /* Milliseconds between requests. */
window.setInterval(function() {
    var val = $("#key").val();
    $("#keypressed").val(val);
    $.get("/My_Servlet/response", { "key": val }, function(data, textStatus) {
        $("#decimal").val(data);
    });
}), interval);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think jQuery implements a timeout function, but plain old javascript does it rather nicely :)

Answer (score 2):

According to [the docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get), jQuery.get's arguments are `url, data, callback`, not `url, callback`.

A call to JavaScript's setTimeout function at the end of your callback function should suffice to get this to continually execute.

Comment: Whatever you like. Use NULL if you don't need any passed along, or you could potentially move key=? from the query string into the data arguments. See the docs for example code.

Comment: "data" is key/value pairs that will be sent the server. Also, the examples at http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get show calls that omit the data parameter.

Comment: hmm... I tried
url = "/My_Servlet/response";
jQuery.get(url, "key=" + escape(key.value), callback);
still wont call the callback function.

Comment: If `callback` is undefined and `data` is a function, jQuery will swap the parameters automatically.

Comment: setTimeout() calls a function once.  setInterval() is the correct function to use when you want something called again and again.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to set the GET parameters on the URL, jQuery will set them automatically. Try this code:

```
var key = document.getElementById("key");
[...]
var url = "/My_Servlet/response";
$.get (url, {'key': key}, function (responseText)
{
    var decimal = document.getElementById ('decimal'); 
    decimal.value = responseText;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I guess it was added the type. This seems to work for me.

```
  function convertToDecimal(){ 
    var key = document.getElementById("key"); 
    var keypressed = document.getElementById("keypressed"); 
    keypressed.value = key.value; 
    var url = "/My_Servlet/response?key="+ escape(key.value);
    jQuery.get(url, {}, function(data){
       callback(data);}
       , "text" );
  }

  function callback(data){
    var decimal = document.getElementById('decimal');
    decimal.value = data;
    clear();
  }
```

Thanks Everyone for the help. I'll vote you up.