# Ajax append load

Tags: ajax, load, append

**it must be jquery**

I have file text.html with 6 div in (a,b,c,d,e,f)

In another file i have a div, i like it to populate the content of a+b+c+d+e+f into that single div

I have try .load = but b remplace a
i have try append, but i need a temp var

so now i am stuck

That code get the content from the file textes.html ... div #a and put the content into div #right, but the second libe REMPLACE the content of right a with right b

I like to append the content a + b NOT a over b

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var temp = load('textes.html #nicolas');
$('#right').append(temp);
var temp = load('textes.html #antoine');
$('#right').append(temp);
.
.
.
.

return false;
});
```

that code is the idea behind what should work, but i cannot make a ajax .load() to load content into a variable to append the content to the div...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){    
$.ajax({
  url: "textes.html",
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    $("#right").append(html);
  }
});
});
</script>
```

That code load the WHOLE html file, i like to get only some selected DIV #

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $.get("textes.html",function(data){
        $("#right").append($("#nicolas",data)).end().append($("#antoine",data));
    },'html');    
});
```

Comment: if fact do you have a simple method to get the .load() content into a var, i will append everything into that var and push it into the div at the end !

Comment: marc, .load() is asynchronous so you can't call it the way you are trying to. I didn't test that code, but that is the way its done. .load() is just a wrapper around $.get which is a wrapper around $.ajax  http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax

Comment: that code load the WHOLE file

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){    
$.ajax({
  url: "textes.html",
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    $("#right").append(html);
  }
});
});
</script>

hod to select witch div i like to get from that file ?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue just now and I think I figured out a way to do what we want using the .load() function. It's not pretty but never mind ;)

First off, I added a "TempDiv" to my html with a "visibility:hidden" style.

```
<div id="TempDiv" style="visibility:hidden"></div>
```

Then you run the jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#TempDiv').load('textes.html #nicolas', function(){
            $('#right').append($('#TempDiv').html());
        });

    });
```

I'm not sure it's the best way !

PS : That is my first stackoverflow post ;)

Answer (score 2):

try,

```
$.get('url.php', function(data) {
    $("#right").append(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like jQuery? Please state what framework you are using since I can't really see any mention of it. Anyway, append should work. Just do something like:

```
mydiv.append(a.text());
mydiv.append(b.text());
mydiv.append(c.text());
mydiv.append(d.text());
mydiv.append(e.text());
mydiv.append(f.text());
```

They should all be appended into mydiv.
NOTE: if you also want the html, use the .html() function instead of .text().

Comment: The div that he wants to load the data into is in another html file so this won't work.

Answer (score -1):

JQuery ( http://jquery.com/ ) is a good javascript library that you can use to do an AJAX request to get the other file. See this question for more: [Use jQuery to replace XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104323/use-jquery-to-replace-my-xmlhttprequest)