# Add Jquery Load Contents to Existing Div Content

Tags: jquery, load

well right now I basically have the jquery load function like this

```
$('#results').load("sources.php?source=1&page=<?=$_GET['page']?>&search=<?=$_GET['search']?>");
```

so it's loading that to the results div, but right after that i'd like to run essentially the same thing but

```
$('#results').load("sources.php?source=2&page=<?=$_GET['page']?>&search=<?=$_GET['search']?>");
```

how could i make it so it simply adds the content of the second load to the results div, as oppose to just replacing the existing content?

Thanks

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861098/ajax-append-load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [get()-function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) instead of load().

```
$.get(url, function(data) {
   $('#results').append(data);
});
```